# Make haskell where clause whitespace insensitive?

Tags: haskell, whitespace, where-clause

I've variously been told you can make Haskell whitespace insensitive with the right use of { ... ; ... ;} Thus far I've been able to mostly do this except with where clauses. Example code which works:

```
primes = 2 : sieve [3,5..] 
    where {sieve = ... };
```

As does:

```
primes = 2 : sieve [3,5..] where {sieve = ...};
```

However this is a parse error:

```
primes = 2 : sieve [3,5..]
where {sieve = ...};
```

Any idea how to make the start of a where clause whitespace insensitive?

Comment: I wiped the comments; [here's the link to the chat to continue discussion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31055/discussion-between-andrewc-and-zorf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the end of [the haskell report's lexemes section](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/lexemes.html#sect2.7) for examples using braces and semicolons.

Here's a simple program I got to compile:

```
module Temp where {
foo = 1           
where x = 2        
}
```

Note the necessity of the braces for the module-level where, due to this part of the report:

> Within these explicit open braces, no layout processing is performed for constructs outside the braces, even if a line is indented to the left of an earlier implicit open brace.

Comment: Ah yeah, I got it, the answer seems to simply be to wrap { ... } around the entire program. .`Module main where` doesn't even seem required, just the braces.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work because your indentation of `where` makes Haskell think `primes`'s definition has ended. It then gets confused because there's a `where` clause left dangling at top level.

You can use `{}` blocks after certain keywords, namely `let`, `where`, `of` (as in `case foo of`) and `do`. So in your case, you just have to omit the newline.

```
primes = 2:sieve [3,5..] where {
sieve = ....
}
primes' = 2:sieve [3,5..] where
{sieve = ...}
```

If you really want it anywhere, you'll have to use an explicit module declaration as well

```
module Main where {
;primes' = 2:sieve [3,5..]
where {sieve = ...}
}
```

I would suggest not doing this and just using indentation however. Explicit braces in Haskell are usually for generated code and when you do see them handwritten it's almost always with `do`.

Comment: Well, this doesn't answer my problem. I was told there are forms of Haskell which make white-space insignificant. I'd like to be able to put the where any-where I want basically no matter the amount of spaces.

Comment: You can't. Simple as that. The Haskell parser will not allow you to mix whitespace sensitive code that you implicitly have without having a `module Main where {` at the top of your file and whitespace insensitive code

Comment: @Zorf see now it should be closer to what you want.